# using named lambda vs function - extra space usage for a variable in case of lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, lambda, c++14

So simplified code snippet (1) would be

```
void f2(someClass* ptr, int x)
{
//some code
}

void f(someClass* ptr, bool cond)
{
//do something with ptr
    if (someConditionThatIsResultOfFunctionWork)
   {
    if (cond)
    {
      //do something else with ptr
      f2(ptr, x1);
    }
     else
        {
          //do something else with ptr
          f2(ptr, x2);
        } 
    }
}
```

code snippet (2):

```
void f(someClass* ptr, bool cond)
{
 auto f2asLambda = [](someClass* ptr, int x)
{
//some code
};
//do something with ptr
if (someConditionThatIsResultOfFunctionWork)
{
if (cond)
{
  //do something else with ptr
  f2asLambda(ptr, x1);
}
 else
    {
      //do something else with ptr
      f2asLambda(ptr, x2);
    } 
}
}
```

Are those code snippets same in terms of performance etc? In case (2) extra variable will be created for the lambda, and we might not call it at all, does it make using function over named lambda preferable?

Comment: you should decide between the two based on whether `f2` belongs inside `f` or not. Performance is the thing you measure when you have working code and then make a decision based on benchmarks ;)

Comment: "... and we might not call it at all" not if you define the lambda inside the `if (someConditionThatIsResultOfFunctionWork)` branch

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number and if in reality it's a bit more complicated with more if-else, so I can't just move lambda into if to be sure that it will be always called, there still be branch that won't call it. So using function would be a better choice?

Comment: Most likely, there's no difference. The compiler will in effect rewrite the second snipped to the first, only `f2` function would be named `SomeClassName::operator()`. `f2asLambda` variable is very likely to be optimized away, seeing as it's an empty object with no data members.

Answer (score 1):

The output produced will be the same unless you start using local variables in the lambda ex:

```
void test(int abc) {
    auto testfn = [&]() {
        return abc + 5;
    };
    testfn();
}
```

Decompiled output:

```
void __fastcall test(int abc)
{
  int v1; // [rsp+20h] [rbp-18h]
  int v2; // [rsp+40h] [rbp+8h]

  v2 = abc;
  lambda_33f9b2a517f89afbe56cddae6ec6364f_::_lambda_33f9b2a517f89afbe56cddae6ec6364f_(&v1, (__int64)&v2);
  lambda_132f59ee0fb0da8eec42827bd7f66058_::operator()((_DWORD **)&v1);
}
```